# handle jquery ajax error

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

in my MVC layout page I have the following:

```
$("body").ajaxError(
    function (e, request) {
        if (request.status == 403 || request.status == 500) {
            window.location = '@Url.Action("LogOn", "Account", new {area = "", msg = "forbidden", returnUrl = HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl})' + window.location.hash;
        return;
        }
        window.location = '@Url.Action("Index", "Error")';
    }
);
```

on another page I'm performing an ajax call like so:

```
...
                $.when(refreshActionLinks(row, machineId, packageId)).done(function(a1) {
                    row.find("span").text(opStatus).removeClass("pending");
                    progressbar.progressbar("destroy");
                    $(row).flash(bg[1], 1000);
                });
...
```

javascript function:

```
function refreshActionLinks($row, machineId, packageId) {
    try {
        var json = JSON.stringify({ packageId: packageId, machineId: machineId, tabType: $("#TabType").val() });
        console.log("refreshActionLinks => " + json);
        $row.find("td.options div.actionLinks").html("<img src='@Url.Content("~/Content/images/ajax-load2.gif")' />"); // pending
        return $.ajax({
            url: "@Url.Action("GetActionLinks", "Packages")",
            data: json,
            timeout: 50000,
            contentType: 'application/json',
            type: 'POST',
            success: function (data) {
                if ($row.length) {
                    $row.find("td.options div.actionLinks").html(data);
                }
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
            }
        });
    } catch(e) {
        // hide icons
        $row.find("a.action").remove();
    } 
}
```

The issue is that while refreshAction function is executing, clicking a menu link causes the ajax call to error out -  which in this case is correct. BUT it does take me to /Index/Error page which is NOT correct. I would like "**$("body").ajaxError**" to handle all ajax errors on the site EXCEPT on the page I'm calling refreshActionLinks. Notice, I already have try/catch surrounding my ajax call. why doesn't that work?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

figured it out:

ajax has a settings:

```
global: false
```

now my function looks like this:

```
function refreshActionLinks($row, machineId, packageId) {
    try {
        var json = JSON.stringify({ packageId: packageId, machineId: machineId, tabType: $("#TabType").val() });
        console.log("refreshActionLinks => " + json);
        $row.find("td.options div.actionLinks").html("<img src='@Url.Content("~/Content/images/ajax-load2.gif")' />"); // pending
        return $.ajax({
            url: "@Url.Action("GetActionLinks", "Packages")",
            global: false, // disable error pages on failed ajax calls
            data: json,
            timeout: 50000,
            contentType: 'application/json',
            type: 'POST',
            success: function (data) {
                if ($row.length) {
                    $row.find("td.options div.actionLinks").html(data);
                }
            }
        });
    } catch(e) {
        // hide icons
        $row.find("a.action").remove();
    } 
}
```